# Registering someone who had a friend buy the tickets

Tags: civievent, best-practice

I have someone who purchased three tickets and I know the names of their guests and they are in the contacts. But, the ticket prices are discounted due to the group rate and was purchased by one person. What is the best way to make sure I have record of someone attending an event if someone else paid for their ticket and the purchase already affected the total count for the event?  I thought of maybe adding them in as a comp, but that would affect the guest count. I want to be able to record in a way that I can make sure they are included on an attendee report.

I am not sure if there is a way to tag additional contact in a particular registration somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add "free" participants from the backoffice to get them on the list. I'm not sure I understood your need about the number of seats, but you could create a status "paid elsewhere" that you set as not counted as taking a seat.

In theory, you can link these participants to the paying "main" participant, but I don't think you can do it from the user interface, you'll have to use the api explorer or code.

Does it solve the problem?

Comment: Yes thank you. The reason I am concerned about the seats is because we have a cap for the attendance. When the head of household purchased 3 tickets that counted as 3. So I wanted a way to name the individuals he bought tickets for, sync to their profiles, and appear on attendee list without affecting our total count.